# How To Make a Small Security Camera?

Tags: design, ldd, piece-usage

I’m looking to make a wall mounted security camera in LDD to mimic this one:
https://icdn5.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/swann-4k-9f-768x479-c.jpg

Any clever ideas? It needs to be angled down like the one in the picture.
White pieces with a black lens. As small as possible, ideally 1x1 Camera body.

Here's what I came up with but it needs a tilt down piece.

[image: security cameras]

Answer (score 25):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Added a Ver.2.Oh*** *belowww*...
[image]

[image]

***[Here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12szqCtSX_jUnWL9dOm2LIxEUTmBLcaIT)*** the *LDD* file if you want it.

***[Here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12szqCtSX_jUnWL9dOm2LIxEUTmBLcaIT)*** the file for *2nd helpings*.  Eat up!

Answer (score 23):

[image: lego security cameras]

I've come up with five different ways to make a micro security camera that look like your reference image.

I'll run through the different methods in the image above from left to right 1 through 5.

### Far left camera 1

[Tile, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138) in black (the lens), [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b) in white (camera body), [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 Rounded with Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26047) in white (the mount), all held by [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Horizontal](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61252) (or part [6019](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6019)).

---

### Camera 2

[Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073) in black, [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b) in white, on [Bar 1L with Towball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22484), held by [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Small Towball Socket on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14704)
This is the only design here that always rotation on more then one axis, which can be a big plus.

---

### Camera 3

[Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073) in black, [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b) in white, on [Bar 1L with Clip Mechanical Claw](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48729) held by [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 Rounded with Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26047)

---

### Camera 4 *(my favorite)*

[Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Bar and Pin Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=20482) in black, [Bar Holder with Clip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11090) in white, held by a [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 Rounded with Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26047)
Just two pieces and looks great.

---

### Far right camera 5

[image: Security camera] [image: Security camera]

Two [Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073) pieces (the lens and body length), a [Tap 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4599a) in white for the body and mount. The camera assembly is held by a [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Horizontal](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61252) (or part [6019](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6019)).